# Security Issues regarding Mutexes

Tags: windows, security, mutex

A **Windows** software installs several Mutexes without applying any permissions to them or rather giving full control to the *Everyone* group.

Is there a way for a *non-privileged* user to take ownership of these Mutexes and change their signal state?

A possible scenario:

A process *P1* calls `WaitForSingleObject` with a Mutex handle, therefore setting it to `nonsignaled`. 
Is it possible for a malicious program *P2* to take ownership of the Mutext (due to the wrong permissions) and set it to `signaled`?

Comment: Well, you can't take a mutex that already belongs to another thread.  But you could wait until it is available, claim it, and then never release it.  (But if it is a local mutex rather than a global mutex then it is only available inside the same terminal services session.  Ordinarily, only the user who is logged into the session will be running programs in it, limiting the security impact of unsecured local objects.)